# Insert aggregation results into an index

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, nest, elasticsearch-aggregation

The goal is to **build an Elasticsearch index with only the most recent documents in groups of related documents** to track the current state of some monitoring counters and states.

I have crafted a simple **Elasticsearch aggregation query**:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_monitor": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "monitor_name"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "get_latest": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [
              {
                "timestamp": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It groups related documents into buckets and select the most recent document for each bucket.

Here are the different ideas I had to get the job done:

1. directly use the aggregation query to push the results into the index, but it does not seem possible : [Is it possible to put the results of an ElasticSearch aggregation back into the index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24813756/is-it-possible-to-put-the-results-of-an-elasticsearch-aggregation-back-into-the)
2. use the **Logstash** [Elasticsearch input plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-elasticsearch.html) to execute the aggregation query and the [Elasticsearch output plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html) to push into the index, but seems like the input plugin only looks at the `hits` field and is unable to handle aggregation results: [Aggregation Query possible input ES plugin](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/aggregation-query-possible-input-es-plugin/28159) !
3. use the **Logstash** [http_poller plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-http_poller.html) to get a JSON document, but it does not seem to allow specifying a body for the HTTP request !
4. use the **Logstash** [exec plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-exec.html) to execute cURL commands to get the JSON but this seems quite cumbersome and my last resort.
5. use the [NEST API](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/) to build a basic application that will do polling, extract results, clean them and inject the resulting documents into the target index, but I'd like to avoid adding a new tool to maintain.

Is there a reasonably complex way of accomplishing this?

Comment: [Watcher](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/watcher/current/index.html)?

Comment: @AndreiStefan Thanks but AFAIK Watcher won't help for this use case. Moreover we don't have it (yet?) deployed on our infrastructure. For alerting we use **ElastAlert** which does the job perfectly too.

Comment: I'm not suggesting Watcher for alerting, but for being able to [query the indices](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/watcher/current/changing-inputs.html#loading-search-results) at a regular interval, do some [basic transformation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/watcher/current/using-transforms.html) on the resulted data and be able to [index back into Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/watcher/current/actions.html#actions-index).

Comment: @AndreiStefan Thanks for these elements. Indeed Watcher seems a good alternative. But as said before we don't have it yet. :'(

Comment: Hey. I have exact the same issue.Did you find a way to directly use the aggregation query to push the results into the index or an work around? Thanks

Comment: @OvidiuRudi Not a direct way, I had to build a dedicated program in C# to make the plumbing.

Answer (score 3):

Edit the `logstash.conf` file as follow

```
input {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost" 
    index => "source_index_name" 
    type =>"index_type" 
    query => '{Query}' 
    size => 500 
    scroll => "5m" 
    docinfo => true
  }
}

output { 
  elasticsearch { 
    index => "target_index_name" 
    document_id => "%{[@metadata][_id]}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it working now thanks to a fix of Logstash? Because at the time of the question Logstash was not handling aggregations.

Comment: yup its working I tried it yesterday only on ELK(5.1.1)

Comment: OK, I trust you, you get my +1. :)

Comment: i don't understand your answer. i've tested it on elastic search 5.1.1 with logstash 5.6.1 and doesn't work. where are you telling  logstash to use aggregation result instead of 'hits' array?

Comment: For this, I have used Elaticsearc 5.5

Comment: @AkshayPatil is not a problem about elastic search version. as you can see from source code [link](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-elasticsearch/blob/master/lib/logstash/inputs/elasticsearch.rb#L168) logstash simply scroll the **hits** array, so it is impossibile to read the aggreggation from elastic search, that are placed in the **aggregations** array in the response of the query. 

the configuration that you have posted simply copy each documents complain the query from source_index_name to target_index_name, so it ignores completely the aggregations values.